# Why adding ROW_NUMBER in View taking too much time to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I use NewID in View then it will take 1 ms,

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[d] 
AS 

  SELECT 
        NEWID() AS Id,
       p.XX
      ,p.xx

  FROM [view_XXX] as P
GO

select * .view_d where code='xxxx'
```

But If I use ROW_NUMBER it will too much time to finish,

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[d] 
AS 

  SELECT 
        Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY T.XXXXXX)  AS Id,
       p.XX
      ,p.xx

  FROM [view_XXX] as P
GO

select * .view_d where code='xxxx'
```

Comment: Because of the `ORDER BY`, I would think. Is there a covering index for that column?

Comment: @Raj then what is the solution.

Comment: Check the answers. Everyone has pretty much given you perfect answers. If you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, then creating an index on the column used in `ORDER BY` will help, but cannot match the speed of using `NEWID()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think,  `NEWID()` always creates any random number as ID(Doesn't need any calculation) But in case of `ROW_NUMBER()` SQL need to order the columns then provide ID.
As `ROW_NUMBER()` is more complex than `NEWID()` SQL server takes more time to process it.

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER()` will have the extra cost of sorting the result but `NEWID()` doesn't have this cost
If you look at the execution plan you can see the same:

> Click on the `Display Estimated Execution Plan` icon on the tool bar `SSMS`

See the below pics.

[image: NEWID()]

[image: ROW_NUMBER()]

Answer (score 0):

There are different requirements behind using a NEWID() or ROW_NUMBER()

For example, for [paging in SQL Row_Number()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-paging-row_number-sql-server-function.aspx) is required. 
Just like Row_Number(), NewID() function will also provide a means of unique values for each data row but will not help you provide SQL paging for example

And NewID() returns different data for same row each time the query is executed. Unless data is not changed, Row_Number() is more less the same